# Can't get basic Observables to work

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I've been learning Angular, and so far I've got the basic foundations down. I want to dive deeper into RxJS and Observables but every time I try to follow tutorials online, there is always these trivials errors, I feel so stupid that I can't solve them, and get stuck on the first step of these tutorials. For example, I'm following Rangle.io's tutorial on Observables, but `.next(42)` `.next(43)`, and `.push(value)` returns error saying `Argument of type '42' is not assignable to paramter of type 'number[]'`.

In some tutorials and RxJS official GitHub, they use `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'` or `import * Rx from 'rxjs'Rx`, but it doesn't work in my project. Can't figure out why I have to use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'` instead of importing everything.

Anyway, what am I missing that is causing the error in the operator?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/observable/from';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  private data: Observable<Array<number>>;
  private values: Array<number> = [];
  private anyErrors: boolean;
  private finished: boolean;

  constructor() {}

  init() {
    this.data = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(42);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(43);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
    });

    const subscription = this.data.subscribe(
      value => this.values.push(value),
      error => this.anyErrors = true,
      () => this.finished = true
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you're declaring that your Observable will produce elements of type `Array<number>` but then you're setting it to produce `number` values.

If you change

`private data: Observable<Array<number>>;`

to

`private data: Observable<number>;`

that should resolve your issue.

Remember that Observables should be set to the type of each object that they will emit e.g. `<number>`, rather than a list or collection of emissions like `<Array<number>>` *

*Unless of course your observable does actually emit a collection of objects every time...

Comment: This is what I see, too. That tutorial is working with ng 2.0.0, and an rxjs  5.0.0 beta. There must have been something amiss back then to allow this.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thanks for pointing that out! Learning angular has proven to be more frustrating than I thought, even though there's an abundance of tutorials online...

Comment: I just updated this one to Angular 4.3 last week if you want to check that out: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents (You can sign up for a free week.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a working Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SA25mG?p=preview

It only has two imports:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

You don't show the HTML, so I assume you have something similar to this plunker?

Comment: Yea, I pasted my code into Rangle's plnkr, and it works. But I don't know why my project is showing error even if I copy the whole code from Rangle's example. I forgot to take out the last import, I was using it trying to make another tutorial work and forgot to take it out.